# Get Id or Name of each li in ul with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get id and text name of each li in ul using jquery

I have tried this but it didn't work

```
<ul id="tags1">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Tags)
    {             
        <li id=@item.TagName >@item.TagName</li>    
    }    
</ul>
```

I have tried this code but it gave me a lot or html

```
$('#tags1 li').each(function (i) {
    alert($(this).html());
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

It gave me that

```
<span class="tagit-label">Art</span><a class="tagit-close"><span class="text-icon">×</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span></a><input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="Art" name="tags">
```

I just need to get the value only value="Art"

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```
$('#tags1 li').each(function () {
    console.log(this.id);  //id
    console.log($('.tagit-label', this).text());  //text
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tags1 li').each(function () {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```